# Is this considered as .NET or IL in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have an old program written in Visual C++ 6. My program contains a lot of pointers (old technology). I did an automatic conversion in Visual Studio 2008 and it compiles and appears to work just fine. Of course, the new codes are still VC++.

The new codes in VS 2008 is basically the same as the old codes, with all pointers remain intact. VS2008 basically just compiles and generate a new executable for me. My questions are:

1. Converted codes are probably not considered as .NET. If I'll develop a new .NET component. Can I use it my program just like any other .NET component?
2. What's the best reflector / obfuscator to view these compiled codes

It's just my experimental project. Can you point me to further reading somewhere online for this topic?

Comment: It has nothing to do with .NET or IL. C++ remains C++

Comment: @Sylence: When its written in msvc6, then it is not C++.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not .Net or IL.  It's still just C++.  Probably (I'm guessing) the only thing that was converted was your project & solution files.  Likely none of the actual code was touched.

Comment: If I need to add a new module (dll) in .NET, do I still need to wrap my DLL before being used (Or make it an ActiveX component)

Comment: @TexasCoder:  That's a completely different question.